# Badges can be repealed when the vote be changed?

Tags: discussion

If my answer score of 25 and I earned "Good answer" badge, then a user canceled his upvote, and my answer has only 24 upvotes.

In this situation, will Stack Overflow repeal my "Good answer" badge?

In Stack Overflow, many badges may encounter the same situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No you won't lose the badge.  Although the next time you have an answer with 25 upvotes, the number of badges wil not change.